# Why saveOrUpdateAll is deprecated in spring HibernateOperations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Take a look into [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/2.5.6/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateOperations.java#HibernateOperations.saveOrUpdateAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

There could be valid reasons behind that, but it's strange that I could do `hibernate.deleteAll` and `hibernate.loadAll`, but not `hibernate.saveOrUpdateAll` (sure I can do that practically, but if this method is deprecated means that it could disappear in next release)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is clear from the Java docs,

> **in favor of individual saveOrUpdate or merge usage**

As you can see the implementation of the method, code taken from the [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/2.5.6/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.java#767),

```
public void saveOrUpdateAll(final Collection entities) throws DataAccessException {
    executeWithNativeSession(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
            checkWriteOperationAllowed(session);
            for (Iterator it = entities.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                session.saveOrUpdate(it.next());
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

This method was less used, it can not be inside your transaction. So, spring want you to iterate the list and save the individual objects.

The `loadAll()` method is different and useful. It is not similar to `saveOrUpdateAll()`.

You are right with your observations that `deleteAll()` is similar to `saveOrUpdateAll()` and I agree that it is inconsistent one is deprecated and the other one is not.

Comment: Thanks Manu, nice explanation! I didn't know that this method can't be used inside transaction.